# asp:TreeView with parent-child relationship in SQL

Tags: c#, recursion, treeview

I wrote some code:

```
 protected void RootNodes()
{
    var contents = ListContentRootNodes(0, this.Culture, true);
    foreach (var content in contents)
    {
        TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode
        {
            Value = content.Title
        };

        List<TreeNode> childNode = ChildNode(content.ContentId);
        if (childNode != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in childNode)
            {
                newNode.ChildNodes.Add(item);
            }
            treeView.Nodes.Add(newNode);
        }
        treeView.ExpandAll();
    }
}

protected List<TreeNode> ChildNode(int contentId)
{
    var subContents = ListContentChildNodesAll(contentId, this.Culture);

    List<TreeNode> nodes = new List<TreeNode>();
    foreach (var sub in subContents)
    {
        nodes.Add(new TreeNode { Value = sub.Title });
        ChildNode(sub.ContentId);
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

**'ListContentRootNodes'** returns first level data rows with **'ParentId'** set to **'-1'**. **ListContentChildNodesAll** calling stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ListChildNodesAll]
@ContentId int,
@Culture nvarchar(5)

AS SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT * FROM Content WHERE ParentId=@ContentId AND Culture=@Culture
```

As far as I searched on net, I've understood that I need recursion method in order to populate rows from **'DB'**, but I could not managed it. I need to create sitemap where all subnodes would be represented. My code is returning only first level and not all child rows. How should I fixed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find solution.My complete working code is :

```
 protected void RootNodes()
{
    var contents = ListContentRootNodes(0, this.Culture, true);
    foreach (var content in contents)
    {
        TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode { Value = content.Title };

        List<TreeNode> childNode = ChildNode(content.ContentId);
        if (childNode != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in childNode)
            {
                newNode.ChildNodes.Add(item);
            }
            treeView.Nodes.Add(newNode);
        }
        treeView.ExpandAll();
    }
}

protected List<TreeNode> ChildNode(int contentId)
{
    var subContents = ListContentChildNodesAll(contentId, this.Culture);
    List<TreeNode> nodes = new List<TreeNode>();

    foreach (var sub in subContents)
    {
        TreeNode nod = new TreeNode { Value = sub.Title };
        nodes.Add(nod);
        List<TreeNode> leafNodes = ChildNode(sub.ContentId);
        foreach (var leaf in leafNodes)
        {
            nod.ChildNodes.Add(leaf);
        }
    }
    return nodes;
}
```